# How to create conditional formating/filters with multiple strings in Microsoft excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to create multiple conditional string formating/filters, say I have a column, and I want to filter out all rows that contain the text, for example:

cats
dogs
horses

Actually there would be hundreds of words, in Google sheets I use a conditional formater like this:

=REGEXMATCH(D:D, ".*(?:cat}dogs|horses).*")

Is there anything like this for excel?

Something simple, no complicated VBA coding?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found my answer, need to use conditional format + custom rule, like this:

=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("cats", D1)), ISNUMBER(FIND("dogs", D1)), ISNUMBER(FIND("horses", D1)))